# calling `echo "test"` in python subproces gives `b'\\test"\n'`

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, cygwin

Why is it that in Python (3.6 in a Cygwin terminal running bash, on Windows 10)

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.check_output(['echo', '"test"'])
b'\\test"\n'
```

NOTE: THE CONFUSING BIT IS THE LEADING BACKSLASH

To make that more clear:

```
>>> print(subprocess.check_output(['echo', '"test"']).decode())
\test"
```

---

Turns out Python2.7 gives me the expected result, but two different Python 3 installations give the wrong one.

---

In my understanding, `subprocess.list2cmdline(x)` should give something that is exactly equivalent when pasted in a terminal as `subprocess.check_output(x)`. In this case though `subprocess.list2cmdline(['echo', '"test"'])==r'echo \"test\"'` and when pasting the latter into the terminal I do get the expected result

```
$ echo \"test\"
"test"
```

---

More tests:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(subprocess.list2cmdline(['echo', '"test"']))
b'\\test"\n'
```

but

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(['echo', '"test"'], shell=True)
b'\\"test\\"\r\n'
>>> subprocess.check_output(subprocess.list2cmdline(['echo', '"test"']), shell=True)
b'\\"test\\"\r\n'
```

Comment: What is your question, exactly? How to convert the returned bytes-string to `str`?

Comment: are you confusing with `subprocess.run(['echo', '"test"'])` ?

Comment: The output should be `b'"test"\n'` for the first command shown, and that's normal: you are seeing the Python *representation* of the string captured by `subprocess`, not just the bytes in the string itself.

Comment: @DeepSpace see the updated question. The output starts with a backslash after proper decoding and unescaping

Comment: @matzeri see the updated question. The output starts with a backslash after proper decoding and unescaping

Comment: @chepner see the updated question. The output starts with a backslash after proper decoding and unescaping

Comment: I cannot reproduce your claimed output: `subprocess.check_output(['echo', '"test"'])` produces the `bytes` value `b'"test"\n'`.

Comment: @chepner are you in cygwin?

Comment: No, but I can't even imagine a scenario where the environment affects the code like this.

Comment: `b'"test"\n'` is the output with Cygwin Python 3.6.13